# Search for the symbol of Napier's number (e) used into wolframalpha

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, packages, wolfram-mathematica

I've been searching since a few days the symbol of Napier's number **(e)**.

It is a symbol of and with a cut on the inside similary to the double struck commands (`\mathbb`). I vaguely remember that there is a package, perhaps distributed by **Wolfram Alfa** in a `.zip` file, which it can to be used in LaTeX documents. Currently I have not been able to find it.

Here there is a ugly screenshot (edit: slightly better screenshot from Wolfram|Alpha):

[image]

**Related question:** [Truncation of Napier’s number (e) to an amount of decimal digits of my choice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522938/truncation-of-napier-s-number-e-to-an-amount-of-decimal-digits-of-my-choice)

Comment: Marijn thank you very muchhhh for the edit my code.

Comment: Please! Wolframalpha's symbol is even worse than writing it upright. Don't do it, please.

Comment: @egreg "Comandi comandante" :-). Just it was only a curiosity and don't worry I will do not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ⅇ U+2147 (`&exponentiale;` in HTML) so should be available in in any font that has double struck italic lower case. So any font used with `unicode-math`  or for pdftex for example the stix and stix2 packages will make it available.

Actually I don't see it in the stix2 package which is surprising, with unicode-math it is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$ \mitBbbe^i $

\end{document}
```

That is latin modern but any OpenType math font will have this.

Comment: I always thank you for your kindness as Marijn that Have edited my question and he has finded a best image. Some time ago I found a series of .zip files that connected to LaTeX but I can't find it no more.

Comment: I have seen (in fact) stix and stix2 package documentation and I have not finded it.

Comment: @Sebastiano if you have mathematica you can use these https://ctan.org/pkg/mathematica?lang=en but I don't think the fonts are generally available any more. But as always you should not worry about the exact character shape, use the font that matches your document. No point in using the mathematica fonts for just one character.

Comment: U+2147 *should* be in stix2; it's certainly in the copy of the reference table I kept when I left AMS, although the name in that table is still `\itBbbe`.  `\mitBbbe`, as in `unicode-fonts`, is the agreed "correct" name.

Comment: I think it should be also a double-struck i for the imaginary unit following the Wolfram conventions: `$^$` or `$ⅇ^ⅈ$`. And a double-struck differential d: `$∫^x \, x = ^x + c$` or `$∫ⅇ^x \, ⅆx = ^x + c$` :)

Comment: @user125730 I wondered about using ⅈ but the whole convention is so horrible I couldn't bring myself to do it other than for the explicitly asked e :-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton neither `\itBbbe` nor `\mitBbbe` is defined in stix or stix2 packages for pdftex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why do you think that this convention is horrible? There is an argument for it: If you use  and , e and i will be free for other usages. For example, `∑_{i=1}^{n} ...` does not disturb any more when you deal with complex numbers. ;) Or something like `d/d = 1` is better than `dd/dd = d²/d² = 1`. OK, my last example is a little bit crazy. :D

Comment: @user125730 some things just look horrible.